# how to install packages directly from github repo in MAC

Tags: git, macos, kubernetes, makefile, colima

Let's say I have to install a package. Obviously, we can use `brew` in mac to install that package. But what if I want to make some changes in the source code of the package and then install it. How do I do this?

To be exact, I am talking about [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) package. Currently, Colima uses k8s version 1.22, but I want to configure it to use an older version by changing some parameters in the source code. How do I do this?

Comment: The general question here is way too broad for Stack Overflow. I suggest you [edit] to remove the general "how can I build things from source"

Answer (score 0):

You need to build this package from source once the specific changes are done. I'm not sure if there is already support available to pass the required K8 version in command line.

You can go to this file here and make the change with the version of kubernetes. The repo needs to be downloaded locally for build.

[Colima kube version change](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/2592399a311cf63db087d8c5c7714847bf133fae/environment/container/kubernetes/k3s.go)

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository, and make the changes you need. Then try these commands:
`make all` and then `make install`. There is also a markdown file named [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/main/INSTALL.md) in the repository which explains how you can build it from the souce.